# Formula that lookup a row and get results like textjoin from non blank cells

Tags: formula, textjoin

Hy all

[image]

I need help with a formula I want result like textjoin but without zeros in empty cell, and to combine a column  name with cell data.
below table is example of results.
with textjoin I get for eg. **Jill = 0,0,2,0,0** i want to skip zeros and combine name from b2:F3 with cell data.
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel's new Filter() function available in 365 versions.

```
=FILTER($B$2:$F$2,INDEX($B$3:$F$7,MATCH(A10,$A$3:$A$7,0),)>0)
&" "&FILTER(INDEX($B$3:$F$7,MATCH(A10,$A$3:$A$7,0),),INDEX($B$3:$F$7,MATCH(A10,$A$3:$A$7,0),)>0)
```

In the screenshot below, the formula has been entered into B10 and copied down to B12. It automatically spills across to the other columns where required.

[image]

**Edit:** This sample is based on your sample data, with positive numbers, hence the check is for number > 0. If you have negative numbers, you need to change the formula. If the cells can contain zeros, please let me know.

Formula for numbers above and below 0

```
=FILTER($B$2:$F$2,INDEX($B$3:$F$7,MATCH(A10,$A$3:$A$7,0),)<>0)&" "&FILTER(INDEX($B$3:$F$7,MATCH(A10,$A$3:$A$7,0),),INDEX($B$3:$F$7,MATCH(A10,$A$3:$A$7,0),)<>0)
```

Comment: Tnx for fasresponse. I am getting a #CALC!
I'll upload a real table screenshot, i thought that I could copy from example, but something went wrong.

Comment: I corrected name it wasn't from first, but same I got #spill #ref and #calc errors

Comment: and forgot to mentioned my cells in table contains formulas.
Tnx again

Comment: I added a formula that works for data with negative numbers.

Comment: Also, in the error screenshot you posted, you had two formulas in one cell.